# Problema al rotar un array

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el siguiente problema, el profesor de algoritmos nos ha pedido "mejorar" el siguiente código y que su funcionamiento sea igual:

```
// Método original
static char[] RotateOld(char[] src, int by)
{
    char[] output = new char[src.Length]; int n = by;

    if (by < 0)
        by = src.Length - by;

    for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
    {
        output[n] = src[i];
        if (n + 1 >= src.Length)
            n = 0;
        else if (n < 0)
            n = by + src.Length;
        else
            n++;
    }
    return output;
}
```

El ejercicio exige intentar remover la mayor cantidad de condiciones que se ejecutan dentro del código (preferiblemente todas) para mayor "rendimiento", esto es lo que he hecho:

```
// Método nuevo.
static char[] Rotate(char[] src, int by)
{
    char[] output = new char[src.Length]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < src.Length; i++)
    {
        output[((i + (by * -1)) + src.Length) % src.Length] = src[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

Sin embargo, al ejecutarlo, pasa lo siguiente, en el primer código (`RotateOld()`), si el parámetro `by` es positivo, el array rota hacia la derecha, es decir, la posición `src[0]` pasa a ser `src[1]`, pero en mi versión "mejorada" ocurre lo contrario, `src[0]` pasa a ser `src[srcLength - 1]`.

Este es un ejemplo de la función original:

```
char[] Input = { 'H', 'o', 'l', 'a' };

char[] Result = RotateOld(Input, 1); // Esto da como resultado: 'a', 'H', 'o', 'l'
```

Y mi versión:

```
char[] result = Rotate(Input, 1); // Esto da como resultado: 'o', 'l', 'a', 'H'
```

¿Por qué para esto?

Comment: No se entiende muy bien lo que deseas, tu ejercicio debe ingresar una palabra y esta devolver la inversa o solo cambiar de lugar una letra en especifico?

Comment: Rotarlo, cambiar de posición el `[0]` hacia `[by]`. si tengo: "Hola" por entrada y quiero moverlo a la derecha por un caracter, la nueva cadena sería "aHol", eso es lo que hacen los códigos anteriores.

Comment: @FernandoM.Goycochea creo que se entiende muy bien: se necesita rotar.

Comment: Gracias NaCi , ahora si lo entendí muy bien.

Comment: Si debes rotar a la derecha, ¿por qué multiplicas el valor de `by` por `-1`? Eso me parece que hace que tu código rote a la izquierda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes rotar a la derecha, así que no necesitas multiplicar el valor de `by` por `-1`. Remueve esa multiplicación del código y quedará como esperas:

```
output[(i + by + src.Length) % src.Length] = src[i];
```

Comment: El -1 lo añadí al tener que rotar a la izquierda, perdón por no expresarlo correctamente en la pregunta, el `array` debe rotar para cualquier lado (izquierda o derecha) con números negativos o positivos, respectivamente.

Comment: Y va a rotar. Pero por defecto, debería rotar a la derecha, si es negativo rotará a la izquierda. Con tu código actual, haces que por defecto rote hacia la izquierda y si envían negativo rotará a la derecha.

Comment: Y pensar que era ese pequeño numero!